# Keras ImageDataGenerator: problem with data and label shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I wanted to generate more images using Keras as you can see in [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/image-augmentation-deep-learning-keras/),
using this code (almost the same as [source>Random Rotations](https://machinelearningmastery.com/image-augmentation-deep-learning-keras/)):

```
# Random Rotations
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras import backend as K
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=90)
# fit parameters from data
datagen.fit(cats["images"])

print(np.asarray(cats["label"]).shape)  #output=(12464,)
print(np.asarray(cats["images"]).shape) #output=(12464, 60, 60, 1)

# configure batch size and retrieve one batch of images
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(cats["images"], cats["label"], batch_size=9):
    # create a grid of 3x3 images
    for i in range(0, 9):
        pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
        pyplot.imshow(X_batch[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))
    # show the plot
    pyplot.show()
    break
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: `x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) should have the same
>   length. Found: x.shape = (60, 60, 1), y.shape = (12464,)

This might help for further inspections :
[image]

I imagine there should be something wrong with the library as if I change the shape of my image into 60x60 instead of 60x60x1 I'll get:

> ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with
>   shape: (12464, 60, 60)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is very likely that the `cats['images']` and `cats['labels']` are Python lists. First convert them to arrays using `np.array` and then pass them to `flow` method:

```
cats['images'] = np.array(cats['images'])
cats['labels'] = np.array(cats['labels'])
```

Comment: I expected the following error for this situation "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'" That is why I never think of that. So much thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the shape of your labels

```
labels = np.asarray(cats["label"]).reshape(( -1 , 1 ))
```

Comment: This does not work and produces almost identical error "ValueError: `x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) should have the same length. Found: x.shape = (60, 60, 1), y.shape = (12464, 1)"